# Finding all roots of a transcendental equation in Python (eg. Bound state solutions of the Finite Square Well potential)

Tags: python, scipy

So I'm trying to solve for the eigenvalues of bound state solutions to the finite square well potential which involves solving the equation:

[image]

I was able to solve it graphically by plotting the two functions and figuring out where they intersect, then using the intersection as an initial guess in scipy.optimize.root. However, this seems like a fairly cumbersome process. From what I understand, root finding methods usually requires an initial guess and finds the local minima closest to the initial guess.

What I'm wondering is if there is a way to find all the roots or all local minima in a given range in Python without necessarily providing an initial guess. From the web searches I've done, there seems to be some methods in mathematica but in general, finding all roots within a good tolerance is impossible except for specific functions. What I'm wondering, though, is whether my equation happens to fall under those specific situations? Below is a graph of the two functions and the code I used using scipy.optimize.root:
[image]

```
def func(z, z0):
    return np.tan(z) - np.sqrt((z0/z)**2 - 1)

#finding z0
a = 3
V0 = 3
h_bar = 1
m = 1

z0 = a*np.sqrt(2*m*V0)/h_bar

#calculating roots
res = opt.root(func, [1.4, 4.0, 6.2], args = (z0, ))
res.x

#output
array([1.38165158, 4.11759958, 6.70483966])
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no general way. 
In this specific case, all roots are well localized due to periodicity of the tangent function, so you can simply run root-findind, e.g. `brentq` on each of these intervals.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a hack rather than an answer, but one may succeed in making the process of root finding a bit less tedious by providing some grid of initial guesses and taking the set of solutions found with all the attempts.
Using `sympy` (whose defaults in `nsolve` may provide a more robust solver) you could do

```
from sympy.solvers import nsolve 
from sympy import tan, sqrt, symbols 
import numpy as np

a = 3 
V0 = 3 
h_bar = 1 
m = 1

z0 =  a*np.sqrt(2*m*V0)/h_bar

z  = symbols('z')

expr = tan(z) - sqrt((z0/z)**2 - 1)

# try out a grid of initial conditions and get set of found solutions
# this may fail with some other choice of interval
initial_guesses = np.linspace(0.2, 7, 100) 

# candidate solutions
set([nsolve(expr, z, guess) for guess in initial_guesses])
```