# find all roots of the system of 2 equations with scipy.optimize

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

`scipy.optimize.root` is finding only one root (as I tried), to which it converges faster, as it is closer to initial guess. In order to solve a bounded [-4;4] system of equations I could create only cycle to find **ALL roots** - with initial visual estimation of init_guess at a glance for further optimization (in cycle):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import root

x = np.linspace(-4,4,100)   

def fs(y):
    return  (2*y**2+3)
def fd(x):
    return x**3+x**2-6*x+3

def obj(x):
    return fs(x)-fd(x)

# visualize approximate bounds to define init_guess for further root func
plt.plot(  x, fs(x), 'r-', x, fd(x), 'b-')
plt.show()

############## optimize    
roots=[]

def find_root( guess):
    res = root(obj, [guess, ],  method='krylov',    tol=1.4e-100)
    if res.success== True:
        roots.append([round(res.x[0],2), round(fd(res.x[0]),2)])
    else:
        res.message
        exit

# cycle:  List Comprehension - 
[ find_root(x) for x in np.array([4.,1.,-1.5], dtype=float) ]

############## plot
r= np.array(roots).T; print(r)

import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame(r, {'x': r[1], 'y': r[0]}).T; print(df)
print(df)

plt.plot(df['x'], df['y'], 'yo', x, fd(x), 'r-', x, fs(x), 'b-', ms=20, )
plt.show()
```

Q: is there in `scipy` any method/function that allows to avoid cycle usage to find all roots & to avoid visual estimation to choose the best initial guesses -- in order to find **ALL ROOTS** programmically ??

Comment: Are you only dealing with polynomials?

Comment: Not exactly, equations are just for the example. But concerning trigonometric equations, I suppose, [periodicity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58477974/finding-all-roots-of-a-transcendental-equation-in-python-eg-bound-state-soluti) can matter. Just wanted to provide non-periodic example . But frankly speaking, would prefer some matrix example (like `A*A^T `) or to work with differential equations `dy/dx`

Comment: Does my solution answer the question? It appears that one of the answers in the periodicity link you shared has a similar approach (though they don't have to round since they're using sympy).

Comment: yes, it does answer

Comment: off: for periodicity I'm just interested sometimes only  in `y = a * np.sin(b*x/2 + c)   +m` for modelling, but still will need some robust objective func for outliers (am confused yet)... perhaps in another Q once..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you will not always be using polynomials, you can avoid manually looping by having `scipy.optimize.root` find all the roots for a large number of initial guesses. This will result in duplicates, but you seem to be rounding already, so you can just round the values and use `np.unique`.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import root


def fs(y):
    return (2*y**2+3)


def fd(x):
    return x**3+x**2-6*x+3


def obj(x):
    return fs(x)-fd(x)

x = np.linspace(-4, 4, 100)
res = root(obj, x)
xroots = np.unique(res.x.round(2))
yroots = fd(xroots)

r = np.vstack((xroots, yroots))
print(r)

plt.plot(x, fs(x), x, fd(x))
plt.plot(xroots, yroots, ".k", zorder=2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: yes, I thought about `np.unique` , just wanted to show the shorter code, because `unique` still doesn't solve the problem of cycle, I thought, but you're right: multiple x as param to objective func together with `unique` gives what I wanted. Thanks for such simple solution (I previously made everything overcomlicated for my shame)

Comment: @JeeyCi If this answers your question then you can accept it.